# printf adding trailing space instead of 0 when doing "printf H%03s 3A"

Tags: bash, printf

On my local mac I developed a bash script which uses `printf`. `printf` here runs fine as expected:

```
$ printf H%03s 3A
H03A
```

The string `3A` is expanded to 3 characters with a leading zero. An `H` is prepended to the variable.

Where I deployed the bash script, `printf` behaves differently:

```
$ printf H%03s 3A
H 3A
```

I can only assume that internally `03A` gets treated as an octal value and therefore the 0 is removed. How can I fix this?

Bash Versions:

On my local mac I have bash 5:

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.0.3(1)-release
```

On the remote machine I have bash 4:

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
4.2.46(2)-release
```

Comment: Add output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) bash bultin is meant to follow the [posix `printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html). The posix `printf` utility follows [XKB File Format Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05) with some exceptions.

Well, In XKB File Format Notation we can read that:

> The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> 0
>   For a, A, d, e, E, f, F, g, G, i, o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) shall be used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the '0' and '-' flags both appear, the '0' flag shall be ignored. For d, i , o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers, if a precision is specified, the '0' flag shall be ignored. For other conversion specifiers, the behavior is undefined.

The flag `0` behavior for `s` conversion specifier is undefined.

> I can only assume that internally 03A gets treated as an octal value and therefore the 0 is removed.

No, it isn't interpreted as an octal number.

> How can I fix this?

Simplest I've come up with is substitute spaces with zeros:

```
printf 'H%5s' "$(printf "%5s" 3A | tr ' ' '0')"
```

It's simple, but surely will fail in case there are spaces in the string. So we need to measure the string length and output that many zeros in front of the string, ex. something like this:

```
printf 'H%5s' "$(str=3A; seq $((5 - ${#str})) | xargs printf '0%.0s'; printf "%s" "$str")"
```

Comment: Assuming there's not going to be spaces in the string, what's wrong with just `printf 'H%3s' 3A | tr ' ' '0'` ?

Comment: @HeathRaftery Nothing.

Comment: is bash v5 handling this differently than bash v4?

Comment: Undefined in the posix means the same as undefined in C. It means you shouldn't do it. When you do it, you break things. Bash didn't "handle it differently", it didn't handle such case at all. That said, I don't see any big changes in the [bash printf](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blame/master/builtins/printf.def#L442). I guess it's the difference in the `printf` implementation in the C standard library in mac and linux, bash seems to just call [vsnprintf](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blame/master/builtins/printf.def#L1053) or printf to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

> For a, A, d, e, E, f, F, g, G, i, o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) shall be used to pad to the field width
>
> For other conversion specifiers, the behavior is undefined.

`%s` is not compatible with 0-padding.